# Is it possible to use xhr for local files?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jqxhr

I can't find any recent answers to this, is it possible to load up a local file using AJAX request. So in my site I have a file called data.json on my web server is it possible to request the date from my Js file using a relative path rather than using its web accessible url and therefore incurring a speed cost.

Comment: Are you asking if you can use a relative path like `../data.json` vs. `http://server.com/data.json`?

Comment: Yeah something like ../data.json

Comment: yes, by doing exactly that. but this is neither local (the browser will still have to request it from the server) nor a speed boost (it's actually a tiny tiny tiny bit slower because the browser has to resolve the relative path to an url first)

Comment: I'm guessing you dont want to make an ajax request to `myserver.com/data.json` instead want the content of `data.json` available to your js. You can read the file on server side, parse it with a json parser and put that into a js variable in your template

Comment: So the json will be in a static file and I would like to parse it in my js file to then render it on my page. When I use a relative path would it be relative to the current url of the page I'm on or the location of the js file. So @nonchip would it be better to just use the actual http:// url

Comment: it'd be relative to the current url, sadly (usually relative to the js file would be more convenient, as you could use the same js file with the same path on any sub pages then), but people usually work around by using e.g. an absolute path without the domain part (e.g. `/path/to/data.json` if it's reachable via `http://your.domain/path/to/data.json`). this also prevents you from hardcoding the scheme, which might be bad if using TLS and/or HTTP2.

Comment: Ah right yeah that would make sense thanks @nonchip could you also if you wanted to use the domain and get around the scheme issue use //domain.com/path/to/data.json. Is there much of a speed hit with the http domain version or is it negligible? If you drop the answer in I'm happy to mark it as correct

Comment: the speed hit is always negligible, cause it's just appending two strings together internally VERY FAST before requesting the page VERY SLOW. but yes, you can (and usually should) also just omit the scheme, starting with `//`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A site with an origin `http://…`, `https://…`, … cannot access content via [`file:///…`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File_URI_scheme&oldid=677179406). Otherwise nothing could stop any arbitrary website from stealing your local data. Probably the buzzword you are looking for is [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

See also: [noscript's ABE](https://noscript.net/abe/), a popular addon that makes the separation between local and remote content even stricter.

See also: [“Firefox exploit found in the wild”](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/08/06/firefox-exploit-found-in-the-wild/), when the separation fails.

Comment: Why local storage will be good once I have the data I still need a way of getting it by using Ajax I imagine.

Comment: Actually, it's worse than that. A page with origin `file://` is not allowed to do XHR at all. So even a page with origin `file://` cannot access content using XHR to `file://`

Comment: @SamMason that might be because your question's topic is asking for exactly that: XHRing local files ;)